# Selecting namespaced XML node attributes with namespace alias instead of URI on an XElement

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to query out some information from a heavily namespaced XML document and am having some trouble finding attributes that are also namespaced.

The XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#"
    xmlns:geo="http://www.geonames.org/ontology#"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
    xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
    xmlns:void="http://rdfs.org/ns/void#">

    <geo:Country rdf:about="http://ontologi.es/place/AD" skos:notation="AD" rdfs:label="Andorra" />
    <geo:Country rdf:about="http://ontologi.es/place/AE" skos:notation="AE" rdfs:label="United Arab Emirates" />
    <geo:Country rdf:about="http://ontologi.es/place/AF" skos:notation="AF" rdfs:label="Afghanistan" />
    <geo:Country rdf:about="http://ontologi.es/place/AG" skos:notation="AG" rdfs:label="Antigua &amp; Barbuda" />
    <geo:Country rdf:about="http://ontologi.es/place/AI" skos:notation="AI" rdfs:label="Anguilla" />
    <geo:Country rdf:about="http://ontologi.es/place/AL" skos:notation="AL" rdfs:label="Albania" /> 
    ...

</rdf:RDF>
```

My goal is to create a list of objects that have a country code and a country name. Here's what works for me now:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"path/to/xml.xml");
XDocument root = XDocument.Load(reader);
XmlNameTable nameTable = reader.NameTable;

XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nameTable);
nsManager.AddNamespace("rdf", "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#");
nsManager.AddNamespace("rdfs", "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#");
nsManager.AddNamespace("skos", "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#");
nsManager.AddNamespace("geo", "http://www.geonames.org/ontology#");

var geoCountries = 
    from country in root.XPathSelectElements("./rdf:RDF/geo:Country", nsManager)
    select new {
        CountryCode = country.Attributes("{http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#}notation").First().Value,
        CountryName = country.Attributes("{http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#}label").First().Value
    };
```

This works fine, but I'd like to find the attributes using the namespace **aliases**, not the namespace URI (just because), or at least be able to lookup the URI using the alias. To try the latter idea, I eventually figured out I could do this:

```
country.Attributes(nsManager.LookupNamespace("skos") + "notation").First().Value
```

But I get an `XmlException`:  The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.

So then I tried:

```
country.Attributes("{" + nsManager.LookupNamespace("skos") + "}notation").First().Value
```

And then it works, but just seems like there could or should be an easier way, or rather, the `{namespace}attribute` syntax seems silly to me, like something that might be abstracted away in the framework.

- **So with all that, are there any shortcuts or easier ways to look up namespaced attributes?**

I'd appreciate any feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

using Linq to xml

```
XNamespace skos = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#");
XNamespace geo = XNamespace.Get("http://www.geonames.org/ontology#");
XNamespace rdfs = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#");

XDocument rdf = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xmlstr));
foreach(var country in rdf.Descendants(geo + "Country"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        country.Attribute(skos + "notation").Value + " "  + 
        country.Attribute(rdfs + "label").Value );
}
```

Comment: For me I had to do: XNamespace w = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml"; Without the "#" at the end.

Answer (score 3):

You can use System.Linq:

```
country.Attributes().Where(a => a.Name.LocalName == "notation")?.First()?.Value;
```