# reading xml file with namespaces in c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

My XML almost starts with

```
xmlns:x="http://schema.metastorm.com/Metastorm.Common.Markup"
```

So to get to attribute x:Name with specyfic x:Type

```
 <x:Object
     x:Name="someName"
     x:Type="{pref_-1582514068:MboField}">
```

I used this linq query:

```
string xmlns = "http://schema.metastorm.com/Metastorm.Common.Markup";

IEnumerable<string> values = from x in xdoc.Descendants(xmlns+"Object")
                       where x.Attribute(xmlns+"Type").ToString().EndsWith("MboField}")
                       select x.Attribute(xmlns+"Name").Value.ToString();
```

However I get error (System.Xml.XmlException) saying that colon character can't be used inside name. Of cours there is one in url.
What am I doing wrong? Is there some way to avoid using colon?

Comment: At least, you could try to google your question title. There are a lot of similar questions here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse XML with namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18230605/how-to-parse-xml-with-namespace)

Comment: I had the same question once before. `xmlns` should be an `XNamespace`. `var xmlns = XNamespace.Get("http://schema.metastorm.com/Metastorm.Common.Markup");`. Keep the rest of your code the same. Here was [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9335902/74757) I received.

Comment: yes, there are a lot of similar questions, but I did it as the solution showed. My namespace contains colon what provokes problem. In example you gave there are no colons in namespace

Comment: @ArkadiuszRaszeja: The example in the answer is using "XXXX" as a placeholder for a regular URI-namespace.

Comment: Ok it Works! I trully forgot use xNamespace.get. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Cory mentioned I used string instead of xNamespace.get. It shuld be:

```
var xmlns = XNamespace.Get("http://schema.metastorm.com/Metastorm.Common‌​.Markup")
```