# Find the attribute value of Xmlns namespace in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

I want to find the squenceID from the above xml:-

```
  <ns2:GetRequest 
    xmlns:ns2='http://www.pcats.org/schema/v01' 
    xmlns:ns4='http://www.pcats.org/schema/core/v01' 
    xmlns:ns3='http://www.naxml.org/2020-10-16'>
    <ns2:RequestHeader>
    <ns2:Version>7.8</ns2:Version>
    <ns3:Name>ZER</ns3:Name>
    <ns2:SequenceID>3</ns2:SequenceID>
    </ns2:RequestHeader>
    </ns2:GetRequest>"
```

I have tried but its values always come null:-

```
 XElement child;
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(requesttcpdata);
XNamespace ns2 = XNamespace.Get("http://www.pcats.org/schema/v01");
child = doc.Descendants(ns2+"SequenceID").FirstOrDefault();
```

[Selecting namespaced XML node attributes with namespace alias instead of URI on an XElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335756/selecting-namespaced-xml-node-attributes-with-namespace-alias-instead-of-uri-on)

Comment: "I have tried ..." but...?

Comment: @HimBromBeere but the value coming is null

Comment: It works. Value = 3.